# get 1 line with the same field in a file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have a file, with contents like:

```
onelab2.warsaw.rd.tp.pl    5
onelab3.warsaw.rd.tp.pl    5
lefthand.eecs.harvard.edu  7
righthand.eecs.harvard.edu 7
planetlab2.netlab.uky.edu  8
planet1.scs.cs.nyu.edu     9
planetx.scs.cs.nyu.edu     9
```

so for each line, there is a number I want the 1st line for each number so for
the content above, I want to get:

```
onelab2.warsaw.rd.tp.pl    5
lefthand.eecs.harvard.edu  7
planetlab2.netlab.uky.edu  8
planet1.scs.cs.nyu.edu     9
```

How can I achieve this? I hope for shell scripts, with awk, sed, etc.

Comment: Where is your effort?

Comment: I reached here and I'm at a loss what to do, using `c` is very troublesome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might work for  you (GNU sort):

```
sort -nsuk2 file
```

Sort the `-k2` second field `-n` numerically keeping the `-s` original order and `-u` remove duplicates.

Comment: Hehe :) It can be really done even shorter than awk (+ expected faster) . `sort` I hadn't in mind. +1 Nice answer!

Comment: +1. You can go one shorter, at least with GNU sort, the last-resort comparison is implicitly disabled when using `-u`. That is `sort -nuk2` is equivalent to `sort -nsuk2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `awk` command for that:

```
awk '{if(!a[$2]){a[$2]=1; print}}' file.dat
```

Explanation:

```
{
  # 'a' is a lookup table (array) which will contain all numbers
  # that have been printed so far. It will be initialized as an empty
  # array on its first usage by awk. So you don't have to care about.
  # $2 is the second 'column' in the line -> the number
  if(!a[$2]) 
  {
    # set index in the lookup table. This way the if statement will 
    # fail for the next line with the same number at the end
    a[$2]=1;
    # print the whole current line
    print
  }
}
```

Comment: Neater than mine; it avoids the END block and prints the lines in the order that they're in the file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm astonished myself again and again how powerful things can be done with awk using a short one liner. :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Check the solution from (at)potong :)

Comment: You can shorten it if you use some of the implicit rules. Each block is preceded by a condition, so you could use: `!a[$2] { a[$2] = 1; print }` or `!a[$2] { a[$2]++; print }`. If you then move the increment outside: `!a[$2]++ { print }`. `{ print }` is the default block when the condition is true, so you can get away with: `!a[$2]++`. Almost shorter than the sort solution :).

Comment: I assume that I'm missing something, but all of your shorteners lead to a syntax error.

Comment: Are you running it like this: `awk '!a[$2]++' file.dat`?

Comment: Clarity is more important than brevity. This is `awk`, not APL!

Answer (score 0):

With sort and uniq:

```
sort -n -k2 input | uniq -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ane 'print unless $a{$F[1]}++' file
```